# Is it possible to display more than 1 item on carousel view?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, carousel

I would like to display 3 items at once on a carousel view on xamarin forms.

I'm using a custom CarouselView that can be found here : https://github.com/AndreiMisiukevich/CardView.
However, it displays only 1 item per view.

Here is a sample of what i've done.

```
  public class Example : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


        private string _titulo;
        public string Titulo
        {
            get
            {
                return _titulo;
            }
            set
            {
                _titulo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Titulo));
            }
        }

        private Color _cor;
        public Color Cor
        {
            get
            {
                return _cor;
            }
            set
            {
                _cor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Cor));
            }
        }

        public Example(string a, Color b)
        {
            Titulo = a;
            Cor = b;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class TesteViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private ObservableCollection<Example> _fonte;
        public ObservableCollection<Example> Fonte
        {
            get
            {
                return _fonte;
            }
            set
            {
                _fonte = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Fonte));
            }
        }

        public TesteViewModel()
        {
            Fonte = new ObservableCollection<Example>()
            {
                new Example("Gratidão", Color.Red),
                new Example("Vitórias", Color.Green),
                new Example("Objectivos do ano", Color.Blue)
            };
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion

    }

    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class teste : ContentPage
    {

        public teste()
        {
            BindingContext = new TesteViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            carrouusel.SetBinding(CardsView.ItemsSourceProperty, nameof(TesteViewModel.Fonte));
        }

    }
```

```
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <card:CarouselView x:Name="carrouusel" VerticalOptions="Start">
                <card:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentView>
                            <Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="200" Padding="0" HasShadow="false" IsClippedToBounds="true" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="{Binding Cor}">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Titulo}" TextColor="Black"/>
                            </Frame>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </card:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
            </card:CarouselView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

I want to display 3 items per view side by side. Like displayed on this image : https://ibb.co/nzphmFw

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/140962/xamarin-form-how-to-show-2-or-3-images-together-using-carousel

Comment: this answer marked as right is not what i would like to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to display 3 item per view side by side, you can custom the `contentView` of `card:CarouselView`, now you only put one `Frame` inside it, you can change it to:

```
<cards:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentView>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="300">

                <Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Padding="0" HasShadow="false" IsClippedToBounds="true" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="Red">
                    <Label Text="Titulo" TextColor="Black"/>
                </Frame>

                <Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Padding="0" HasShadow="false" IsClippedToBounds="true" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="Green">
                    <Label Text=" Titulo" TextColor="Black"/>
                </Frame>

                <Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Padding="0" HasShadow="false" IsClippedToBounds="true" CornerRadius="0" BackgroundColor="Yellow">
                    <Label Text="Titulo" TextColor="Black"/>
                </Frame>

            </StackLayout>

        </ContentView>
    </DataTemplate>
</cards:CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
```

This will display 3 labels each view. Let me know if it works.

**Update:**

I edited code of CoverFlowView and I think it's almost success. You can check my sample here:  [cards-View-xamarin.forms](https://github.com/XfHua/cards-View-xamarin.forms)

I changed :

```
PositionShiftValue="250"
```

and give a `widthrequest` and `heightRequest` to the image.

Comment: Yes. It will display. But animation when swiping to next item will also show next 3 items apearing and not just 1. I would like the swipe to show the next element displayed within the 3 displayed in the current content view.

Comment: @Kelve You want the first view shows 3 items and next view only shows 1 item?

Comment: @Kelve Or you want the CarouselView is scrollable and the items appears one by one and there are always 3 items on the contentView?

Comment: Yes @Jack, the 2nd option. I want to display the 1st item(the one that is selected) and the next 2 items. When the user makes swipe, the next item displayed in the content view will be selected.

Comment: @Kelve I think you have to use a [CollectionView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction) instead of a CarouselView.

Comment: But will it be possible to scroll to only next item ? With collectionview, after scroll it will not stop on next item depending on how strong the swipe was.

Comment: @Kelve I know there is property called `isPagingEnabled` in iOS for UICollectionView. This means u have to use custom renderer, I will try it later and let you know the result.

Comment: Did u try? I really would appreciate your help. Even if its needed to create a custom renderer, u could give me some link where i could learn how to do such.

Comment: I'm trying but haven't get success yet.

Comment: Did u check github link ? They have a control that is very close. But just shows preview of previous and next element. `CoverFlowView`. Maybe could change something in the renderer to display 3 items at same time.

Comment: @Kelve I have updated my demo in my question and I think it is almost success. Check it and let the know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

The HorizontalListView I created here handles this scenario:

https://github.com/roubachof/Sharpnado.Presentation.Forms#horizontallistview-and-grid-mode

You just have to set the `ColumnCount` to 3 and snap to start or center as you like:

```
<renderedViews:HorizontalListView Grid.Row="3"
                                  Margin="-16,8"
                                  CollectionPadding="8,8"
                                  ItemSpacing="8"
                                  ColumnCount="3"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding SillyPeopleLoader.Result}"
                                  SnapStyle="Start">
```

You can also find the blog post in details here:

https://www.sharpnado.com/carousel-layout-happy-new-horizontallistview/

Comment: Hi. Just 1 question, is it possible to have cyclical list ?